# Node opening/closing logic for a basic TreeView

Tags: angular, typescript

So I'm making a basic TreeView, just to list a directory structure having components:

**MyTreeMenuComponent [TypeScript] (Parent):**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mytree-menu',
  template: `<div style="margin-left:30px">
                <mytree [treeItems]="treeItems"> Loading.. </mytree>
                <ng-content></ng-content>
            <div>`,
})

export class MyTreeMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  treeItems: any;
  constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchFileList(); // function assigns directory listing to `treeItems`
  }
}
```

**MyTreeComponent [TypeScript] (Child):**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mytree',
  templateUrl: './mytree.component.html',
})

export class MyTreeComponent {
  @Input() treeItems: any;
  constructor(public omni: OmniService) { }
  setSelection(val: any) {
    this.omni.selectedFile = val;
  }
}
```

**MyTreeComponent [HTML]:**

```
<li *ngFor="let item of treeItems?.children">
  <a (click)="showList = !showList; setSelection(item)">
    {{ item?.name + (item?.isFile ? "" : " [" + item?.size + "]" ) }}
  </a>
  <ul *ngIf="showList">
    <mytree [treeItems]="item"></mytree>
  </ul>
</li>
```

In the HTML file, you can see it's made recursive so that the tree continues to be created with sub-nodes as long as it has children. It's pretty basic and I don't want any fancy functionalities, so I'm not going for any 3rd party options. Everything *works fine*, **except** for the flawed node open/close logic:

[image]

Clicking on a node opens/closes it's adjacent nodes. What am I doing wrong here or what more can be done in the HTML or the TypeScript, so that only the clicked node opens/closes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

Added a boolean `isExpanded` in the `item` interface and then:

**MyTreeComponent [HTML]:**

```
<li *ngFor="let item of treeItems?.children">
  <a (click)="setSelection(item)">
     {{ item?.name + (item?.isFile ? "" : " [" + item?.size + "]" ) }}</a>
  <!-- Replace `*ngIf="showList"` with `*ngIf="item.isExpanded"` -->
  <ul *ngIf="item.isExpanded">
     <mytree [treeItems]="item"></mytree>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**MyTreeComponent [TypeScript] (Child):**

```
//codes above
setSelection(val: any) {
    this.omni.selectedFile = val;
    val.isExpanded = !val.isExpanded; //added this
}
```

Now everything works fine as expected.